# print a form with texts in c# that looks like a word document

Tags: c#, printing

i am trying to create a contract (document) that I can print like a normal word document.
I have a form which is my 'entry form') where i can type in details such as customer name, amount,date of contract etc. these information is then saved in ms access. 
i have another form (which i call 'contract doc'). it has labels in it and the label holds the information i typed in my 'entry form'. I assigned one label to get the values that i entered in the textbox in the entry form.

```
    contractdoc.contract_date_label.Text = contract_date_tb.Text;
    contractdoc.deposit_label.Text = deposit_tb.Text;
    contractdoc.customer_name_label.Text = customer_name_tb.Text;
```

i also added labels and typed the rest of the documents body and position them in the 'contract doc form ' to look like an actual contract.
but i dont know how to print it like a document. i iused :

```
    printForm1.Print();
```

but what happens is, it asks me to save in xls format and only a messege box that says:"printing page 1 of document" with a cancel button.

I hope you can help. thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of trying to print a form, I suggest you create an actual document and print that. You could use Microsoft's Primary Interop Assemblies to automate Word, or find a third-party library that creates files in the .docx format, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I presume from the name `printForm1`, that you're using the [`PrintForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.aspx) class provided as part of the Visual Basic PowerPack.

In that case, you need to make sure that the [`PrintAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.printaction.aspx) property is set appropriately. To print to a physical printer, you need to set it to `PrintAction.PrintToPrinter`. Depending on what printer is configured as the system default, you might also need to set the [`PrinterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.printersettings.aspx) property. Then when you call the [`Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918024.aspx) method, it will print to the correct printer.

It's probably prompting you to save the file in XLS format because your system default printer is a virtual one that generates XLS files.